# jQuery stop not working for multiple drop down when clicked multiple times

Tags: jquery

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vCxto)

HTML

```
<div style="margin: 0;" class="btn-toolbar">
              <div class="btn-group">
                <button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn dropdown-toggle">Action <span class="caret"></span></button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div><!-- /btn-group -->
              <div class="btn-group">
                <button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle">Action <span class="caret"></span></button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div><!-- /btn-group -->

            </div>
```

Here is the jQuery

```
$('.btn').unbind().click(function(){
  $('.btn.active').next('.dropdown-menu').slideUp() //Comment this 
  $('.btn.active').removeClass('active'); //Comment this 
  $(this).stop().toggleClass('active');
  $(this).next('.dropdown-menu').stop().slideToggle();
})
```

This is the basic code.

My issue is when the `btn` is clicked multiple times the dropdown opens/close multiple times.

Previously I had only one dropdown which was working fine.
Later I added one more dropdow for which I added two line of jQuery for removing `active` class and close other dropdowns.

If you comment the first two lines and check you find it working fine.

It will be great if you can guide me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What should happen if the user clicks the button mid-animation? Should the click be ignored, or should it toggle the state?

Assuming the latter, it's probably best to add the class when the animation has completed, and exclude the button being clicked (`$(this)`). That should do the trick.

Check out [this revised codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/HGkAz).

Comment: This is not working. Can you tell me what is not clear? so I can describe it some more.

Comment: @user3773599 Ah, I've re-read the question - I think I just misunderstood. I'll do a new pen and revise my answer. Sorry!

Comment: @user3773599 I've updated my answer now that (I think) I'm interpreting the question correctly. Hope this helps!

Comment: you are added active class which is not removed. I need to remove the active clas once the dropdown in closed.

Comment: [Here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hEAvB) is the updated code add it to you answer. Thanks again.